# on clicking home button media player activity get closed/destroyed and back it to the previous activity

Tags: android, audio-player, android-homebutton, android-music-player

[Here is my music player that seems to be closed while pressing home button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hfqq.png)

Comment: Are you using a service?

Answer (score 0):

If it's destroyed, it could be a crash, but you said that it goes back to another Activity, therefore it must not be a crash. Another possibility is that your are calling finish() either on onPause or onStop.

Comment: here is my code  @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mp.pause();
        playBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
        super.onPause();
    }

Comment: Are you explicitly finishing that Activity somewhere in you code as a result of some computation?